# NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to find or access element tags

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I cannot locate the *username* and *password* fields. I inspect the elements, and tried finding it by id, xpath or css selector, but it gives me error NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time 



if __name__ == "__main__":
    option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    option.add_argument("--incognito")
    option.add_argument("--start-maximized")

    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        chromedriver_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "chromedriver.exe")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, options=option)
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

    driver.get("https://www.wix.com/")
    loginPage = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/header/nav/a[2]"))).click()

    usernameField = driver.find_element_by_id("input_4")
    passwordField = driver.find_element_by_xpath("input_5")

    usernameField.send_keys("user")
    passwordField.send_keys("pass")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

The error I get is:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"input_4"}
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: I do not see an `input_4` on that page, I only see `input_1` and `input_2`. Also, in `find_element_by_xpath("input_5")` that is not a valid XPath.

Comment: For me it appears as `input_0` and `input_1`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to locate `email` and `password` fields you can try

```
usernameField = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email")))
passwordField = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password")))
usernameField.send_keys("user")
passwordField.send_keys("pass")
```

The reason why you cannot locate fields:

- `driver.find_element_by_id("input_4")` - I see no elements with `id="input_4"`. `@id` value might be dynamic.
- `driver.find_element_by_xpath("input_5")` - `"input_5"` is not valid XPath syntax. You might need to use `//*[@id="input_5"]`, but anyway I also see no elements with `id="input_4"`...

Comment: Thanks! it works. For me it appeared as "input_4" that is why I used that. And the xpath I was using "//*[@id="input_5"]" I just forgot to change it to id when I post it. But I also want to ask, why do I need to wait? What is the reason?

Comment: @paul , because those input fields are not present in page source so you need to wait until they apper in DOM

Answer (score 0):

The elements i.e. **username** and **password** fields are [Angular](https://angular.io/) elements and becomes *visible*, *enabled* and *clickable* once you invoke `click()` on the element with text as **Sign In** and *JavaScript* / *AjaxCalls* are completed. So you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Minimal Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.wix.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign In"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']"))).send_keys("paul")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']").send_keys("paul")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: wix_login]

> **Note**: You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)